# Ajax request with DELETE method not wroking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the following Ajax request for deleting comment from database.  My code

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/comment/deleteComment',
            type: 'DELETE',
            data: {commentId: Id,username: Username } ,
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            success: function(data){
                            alert("Success")
                         },
            error: function(){
                            alert("failed")
                         }
        });
```

But in my network console I am getting following message in console header

```
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Request URL:http://localhost/comment/deleteComment
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:403 Forbidden
```

Comment: It is your back end code that this issuing the Forbidden error, so please post the appropriate back-end code.

Comment: I checked the backend URL .It's working perfectly.But the URL is not working in AJAX request

Comment: Maybe it's CORS problem try to add `crossDomain: true,` to Ajax

Comment: Is the server set up to allow deletes? I am pretty sure the issue is with the server, has nothing to do with the clientside.

Comment: yes , server set up is enabled for delete

Comment: What if you just do `url: '/comment/deleteComment'` instead of the full URL? The fact that your DELETE request turns into an OPTIONS request *strongly* suggests this is being treated as a cross-origin request. Could this be a `127.0.0.1`-versus-`localhost` problem? (Those are two different origins.)

Comment: Well look at the server logs and see what is going on.

Comment: In the header of your HTTP request set: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *` I suspect that right now your API is either rejecting your request, a) because CORS is not enabled or b) You have not allowed `DELETE` as an appropriate method.

Comment: Your "Remote Address" is on port 8080 (so your page is probably being server from port 8080), but your request is going to default port 80. Is that correct? In any case, it's definitely a cross-origin request. Are you intentionally running two services, one on port 80 and one on 8080? You should make that **much clearer** in your question.

Comment: How did you go about testing your back-end URL, from a browser? from a API testing tool that will do an AJAX DELETE request?  If you tested from a browser then you would have been testing a GET and not a DELETE.

Comment: Wwe can test AJAX DELETE request through the Chrome browser plugin. My URL is perfectly working in that plugin.@Mark Stratmann